# Existence of a (purely) non-atomic probability measure in a compact metric space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, operator-theory

Given a compact Hausdorff space $X$, it is proved in this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93088) that, if a probability measure $\theta$ contains an atom, then the atom is the union of a singleton and a $\theta$-null set. Also, it can be shown that, if we view $C(X)$ as a $C^*$-Algebra, a state is an extreme point of the closed unit ball of $C(X)^*$ iff the GNS-representation associated to that state is irreducible. Since an irreducible representation of $C(X)$ coincides with a point-evaluation, then the set of extreme points of the closed unit ball of $C(X)^*$ is the set of all Dirac measures.

Now by [Krein-Milman Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Milman_theorem), the weak-$\ast$ closure of the convex hull of the set of Dirac measures is the set of all probability measures. If my reasoning above is correct, my questions are:

> **Updates**: **Corollary 8.1** (whose proof is in **Theorem 8.1**), in *Probability Measures in Metric Spaces* written by **K. R. Parthasarathy**, shows that, in particular in a compact metric space, the set of non-atomic probability (Borel) measure is weak-$\ast$ dense in the probability measure space. If the general form exists remain unknown although **Theorem 6.3** in the same reference approves my reasoning above. A measure like $\sum_{i\geq 1}r_i\delta_{x_i}$ for a sequence of positive real number that sums up to $1$ clearly has atoms.

1. Does $X$ has any non-atomic probability (Borel) measures (**Yes**), and can we know the general form of a non-atomic measure?

Comment: General form of a non-atomic measure? Tooooooo optimistic.

Comment: If a non-atomic measure exists, I suppose it always have the form in Q2, but a counter-example is definitely welcomed.